# What is the difference in assigning output before end process and after end process in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have written a code to check the difference in assigning output before "end process" and after "end process" in VHDL. And the results of the simulation I have posted with it. 
[image]
[image]
What I found is assigning output 
1:After "end process" there is no delay, output port is reflected with change in variable.
2:Before "end process" there is a pulse  delay.
but I'm not able to conclude it.

```
entity signal_delay is 
port (clock_50M: in Std_logic;
        r: in std_logic;
        r_delay1, r_delay2: out std_logic);
end signal_delay;



architecture ada of signal_delay is 

 signal r_1,r_2: std_logic;

 begin 
     process(clock_50M)
     begin 
        if ( clock_50M='1') then 
            r_1<= r;
            r_2<=r_1;
        end if ;
     end process;

    r_delay1<=r_1;
    r_delay2<= r_2;

 end ada;
```

----case:2-------------------------------------------------------------

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity signal_delay is 
port (clock_50M: in Std_logic;
        r: in std_logic;
        r_delay1, r_delay2: out std_logic);
end signal_delay;


architecture ada of signal_delay is  

signal r_1,r_2: std_logic;

begin 
    process(clock_50M)
    begin 
        if (clock_50M 'event and clock_50M='1') then 
            r_1<= r;
            r_2<=r_1;
        end if ;
        r_delay1<=r_1;
        r_delay2<= r_2;
    end process;

end ada;
```

Comment: It would be nice if the code was formatted a little!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sequential process the signal is assigned with the next event.
If it is not in a clocked process the signal is assigned immediately.

But another thing is you have this block in your VHDL description:

```
process(clock_50M)
begin 
    if (clock_50M 'event and clock_50M='1') then 
        r_1<= r;
        r_2<=r_1;
    end if ;
    r_delay1<=r_1;
    r_delay2<= r_2;
end process;
```

This is not synthesised in a way you want.

1. You should put the r_delay1 <= r_1; and r_delay2 <= r_2; inside the if to determine on which clock edge it should happen. There are no Flip Flops reacting to both.
2. Do not use *clock_50M 'event and clock_50M='1'* use *rising_edge(clock_50M)* it is more readable